# Refreshing URL in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am still trying to learn web scraping, so I was wondering what method do I need to use to refresh the webpage without closing R? Because as of right now, when I access the URL and grab data from it using methods from rvest, I always get the same output no matter when I run it unless I restart R.

Edit: in order to get what I am looking for, the first song at the top, I

```
song <- myurl %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(".track-list-item:nth-child(1) .track-artist span , .track-list-item:nth-child(1) .track-title span") %>% html_text()
```

Where myurl is https://washfm.iheart.com/music/recently-played/

Comment: You're getting the same data each time you call `rvest::read_html()`?  What's the web site?

Comment: https://washfm.iheart.com/music/recently-played/

Answer (score 1):

That web page is updating itself dynamically. Poking around with the developer tools you can see that it's calling an API every 100 milliseconds or so. If you're interested in the current song that's playing you can call that API, too with the `jsonlite` package:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)

current_song <- jsonlite::read_json(
  "https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2501/currentTrackMeta?defaultMetadata=true")

current_song %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  glimpse()
```

**Output:**

```
Rows: 1
Columns: 14
$ artistId       <int> 4829
$ albumId        <int> 24001596
$ trackId        <int> 24001628
$ title          <chr> "Need You Tonight"
$ artist         <chr> "INXS"
$ album          <chr> "The INXS Collection 1980 - 1993"
$ trackDuration  <int> 182
$ imagePath      <chr> "http://image.iheart.com/ihr-ingestion-pipeline-production-wmg/new_release/20170208141436987/603497908929/resources/6…"
$ explicitLyrics <lgl> FALSE
$ lyricsId       <int> 2321844
$ startTime      <dbl> 1.64564e+12
$ endTime        <dbl> 1.64564e+12
$ playbackRights <named list> TRUE
$ dataSource     <chr> "Pnp"
```

Note that what's returned by the API is current. It may not match what's on the web page, which takes a little time to update. Also note that what's returned by the API is different during commercial breaks, or when a song isn't playing, so you'd have to handle those conditions. Finally, I've no idea how iHeart feels about you calling their API, so you need to investigate that on your own and use it in accordance with their terms.